# Spring IllegalState unable to create datasource erratic behavior on unit test

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, startup

Since a few days back I've been having erratic behavior from my server when test are run. When test start sometime -- without any apparent reason. I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
...Or error creating datasource.
```

What I get from here is that the properties files cannot be properly read. I have forced the app to read the properties files and still get the same kind of error.

I deleted all added dependencies since error appear (Firebase admin SDK) and deleted all configuration that may be related. But still getting completely unexpected results, sometimes the server run without problem, sometime it just fails and fails, and the only think that seems to return to work regularly is to clean the dependencies (mvn clean install -U).

I am running the server on Intellij Idea 2018.1.5.

Any kind of hint of what is going on would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

If mvn clean and -U works, I suspect that for some reason your maven dependency set up brings more than one artifact, one with release version and the other with SNAPSHOT version, and both artifact exists in the same target directory (e.g, /target/WEB-INF/lib if yours are webapp running in Tomcat).

Also there is a possibility that your local maven repo ($YOUR_USER_NAME/.m2/repository/~ if yours are Mac), has old SNAPSHOT that has bug inside or not the one you want to use, and it keep gets updated with latest one when you use run mvn with -U but then mvn brings back bad SNAPSHOT whenever you run mvn without -U.

Or

It's possible that your mvn module that includes the unit test has different artifact version than it supposed to be depends on how your maven module is organized.

Try first by deleting your local maven repository(everything under .m2/reposityr/ or specific repo directory if you know what it is) and do mvn clean build.

Comment: I check for any conflict, and indeed there was one, I excluded the conflicted dependency. Then deleted the whole repository. And still having the same unstable behavior. I even deleted many non-conflicted libraries and no change. 
This is really driving me crazy!

Comment: Do you have additional logs? I guess there should be more logs than what you posted in the question, including more "caused by... " section. Since Spring failed to create or inject datasource bean, log should tell you something.